# Teste da ausência de tuplas duplicadas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Vi em um livro de SQL a seguinte consulta:

```
select T.course_id from course as T where unique (select R.course_id from section as R where T.course_id = R.course_id and R.year = 2009)
```

Não estou conseguindo aplicar essa consulta no SQL Server, o que eu coloco para substituir o unique e retornar a sub-consulta sem tuplas duplicadas?

Comment: `where unique` é uma sintaxe do `Oracle`, no `SQLServer` use `distict`

Comment: Mas o distinct não funciona depois do where, somente no select, por isso não sei como aplicar isso com uma sub-consulta. Até coloquei o distinct no select mas não funciona.

Comment: sim, o distinct é usado nos campos do `select`. Veja minha respostas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa sintaxe é usada no `oracle`, para o `sql-server` use `distinct`.
Essa subquery pode ser usada com `exists`, já que o `distinct` faz parte do `select`, então a query ficaria assim:

```
select distinct T.course_id 
  from course as T 
 where exists (select R.course_id 
                 from section as R 
                where T.course_id = R.course_id and R.year = 2009)
```